# Increment file number using zmv

Tags: zsh, rename, batch-rename

I have a set of files that are named in the vein of "some_file-nameN", where N is a number starting at 1, incrementing, and ending somewhere between 10 and 30. I now need to insert a file at the start. How can I increment the number of the file using ZMV and ZSH?

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the directory containing the files, and assuming the range is 1 to 30:

```
for n in {30..1};
mv some_file-name$n some_file-name$(( $n+1 ))
```

Comment: worked for me--thanks for posting. It looks like `zmv` doesn't provide this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `zsh` can do it.

```
zmv '(some_file_name)(<->)' '$1$(($2 + 1))'
```

This should work for any number of files.

Comment: This would overwrite FILE2 with the contents of FILE1, then overwrite FILE3 with the contents of FILE2, and so on, leaving you with a single file.  As such, it actually returns an error:

    % ls
    FILE1 FILE2 FILE3 FILE4 FILE5 FILE6 FILE7 FILE8 FILE9

    % cat *
    FILE1
    FILE2
    FILE3
    ...

    % zmv -n '(FILE)(<->)' '$1$(($2 + 1))'
    zmv: error(s) in substitution:
    file exists: FILE2
    file exists: FILE3
    ...